# How can I get the date after clicking on calender in yearly view in dhtmlx scheduler?

Tags: dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

When i click on a date i need to take the selected date, it's working fine on daily, weekly and monthly view by using code below :

`scheduler.attachEvent("onEmptyClick", function(date , event){
    alert(date);
});`

but, the date variable don't return a correct value in case of yearly view

Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above will not work in next two cases

- clicking on date with events ( not empty click )
- clicking on month name, week name or empty space ( onEmptyClick event will be triggered, but will have null instead of date )

Only clicking on day cells will trigger onEmptyClick event with valid date.

Answer (score 0):

A little late but here is the solution, since i ran into the same issue

```
scheduler.attachEvent("onClick", function (id, e){
  var clickedDate = scheduler.getActionData(e);
  console.log("clickedDate", clickedDate.date);      
});
```